# how to convert form AABB space (get_center method) to world environment in godot 4

Tags: godot, gdscript, 3d-modelling, aabb

I use get_AABB in godot 4 which is bounding box of mesh, I actually use get_center which is center of mesh. my question is get_center which is vector3 is in world environment space or mesh environment? how can I convert from mesh environment to world environment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_aabb` method form `VisualInstance3D` returns an `AABB` in its local space.

To get it in global coordinates do this:

```
visual_instance.global_transform * visual_instance.get_aabb()
```

Be aware, of course, that an `AABB` can't represent rotation, so what this is doing is transforming the extreme points of the AABB, and giving you the smaller AABB that contains them. The center position will be correct, but there is no guarantee that it will preserve its size.

Each class that extends `VisualInstance3D` provides its own implementation. In the case of a `MeshInstance3D` you get the bounding box of its `mesh`.

Another caveat worth mentioning is that you get the `AABB` of the `VisualInstance3D` itself, disregarding children.

---

**Addendum**

The above is code for Godot 4. As you are aware, in Godot 3 there was a `get_transformed_aabb` method. However it was removed to avoid confusion on what it did, and because it is easy to reimplement, as it did the same thing as the code I posted above. See: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/66940

About getting the scale, you can find how the transform scales the object like this:

```
visual_instance.global_transform.basis.get_scale() * visual_instance.get_aabb().size
```

*Here we are doing a component-wise multiplication (a.k.a direct product) of the two vectors (not to be confused with dot product or cross product).*

Here `visual_instance.global_transform.basis.get_scale()` gives you the scaling *before rotation*.

---

You can, of course, use the size of AABB:

```
(visual_instance.global_transform * visual_instance.get_aabb()).size
```

But is not the same thing. As the latter is size of the `AABB` that contains the extreme points of the original `AABB` after transforming them (including rotation and scaling).

Comment: in godot 3, we have get_transformaabb. also your formula in ok in godot 3 but not in godot 4. i tested it @Theraot

Comment: also, how to find size after scaling ?

Comment: @Ehsan I've been using this in Godot 4, and it seems to be working.  Perhaps I'm not clear on what you want. I have updated the answer about size and scaling, and why `get_transformed_aabb` was removed.

Comment: Thanks it works@Theraot, how to do above process  inversely, I mean change coordinate from World Space to Mesh Space?

Comment: @Ehsan You can get the inverse of the transform. Using `affine_inverse` should work.